# Maps.newDirectionFinder() Exceeded Daily Request Quota

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using a GAS embedded into a Google spreadsheet to act as a mileage log.  After the user enters their origin and destination, my script automatically calculates the distance and inputs it into the spreadsheet.  It works perfectly, except half the time it tells me:

{error_message=You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_, routes=[], status=OVER_QUERY_LIMIT}

I am definitely nowhere near the daily request quota.  The relevant part of my code is as follows:

```
var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(orig)
    .setDestination(dest)
    .getDirections();
```

It throws the error at .getDirection().  I would greatly appreciate any insight into this problem.

Comment: You should add a key to the request as recommended (it is now required).

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add a key to the request as recommended (it is now required).