# Use an API key in Google Apps Script "Maps" class

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

We're starting to work with [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and Google Apps in general where I currently work. I've been searching and searching in Stack Overflow to try to solve this problem:

We have a Google Spreadsheet in which we calculate the total distance between the different points in a route. Something like this:

[image: Example-google-spreadsheet]

In my Apps Script, I have this piece of code:

```
 var directionFinder = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  directionFinder.setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING);
  directionFinder.setOrigin(origin);
  directionFinder.setDestination(destination);
```

I run the function and sometimes works and sometimes don't. What annoys me is when I go to my Google Cloud Console, in my API administration, I don't see any API usage - it's like nothing happened, even if I have enabled the API.

---

I know my question is exactly the same as in these links:

- [Maps.newDirectionFinder() Exceeded Daily Request Quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229484/maps-newdirectionfinder-exceeded-daily-request-quota)
  In this link I don't understand how I can add my API to the request like the error info recommends.
- [Set Maps API key in Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948812/api-key-in-script-editor)
  In this one, the code worked for me and I see movement in my API administrator.

The thing is, is it possible to do it using the `Maps` method and not using `UrlfetchApp`? Currently using `Maps`, I don't see anything happening and it works whenever it wants.

I have seen there is a method in `Maps`, something like:

```
Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey)
```

I tried putting here my `projectId` and API key, but I think it did nothing.